# Multiple finder preference plists in mavericks

Tags: macos, finder, plist

I’ve had a very sluggish Finder recently on my Mid-2012 MBP 16GB 2.6GHz i7.

Looking online I found that deleting the Finder preferences can solve the issue, but when I went to the `Preferences` folder to look for `com.apple.finder.plist` I also found files like these: `com.apple.finder.plist.DUkfEQe` and `com.apple.finder.plist.DUkfEQe2` and others with random strings at the end. Any idea what these are and which one is my 'actual' finder plist?

Answer (score 1):

The `com.apple.finder.plist` file is the actual file.  I believe the ones with a random extension are renamed originals used to hold the changes until the .plist file is updated and then are deleted.